# Why is the body of request empty?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a pattern from another project for sending JSON-data to node. In the other project it works, in this project not. 
The req-object is valide, but the body is empty. Why?

Client-side:

```
json = { "auth_user_pkref": 2 }
        json.test_id = "ANCA"
        json.questions_count = 3
        json.right_answers = 2
        json.wrong_answers = 1
        json.seconds_spent = 180

        console.log('/api/answer/add', json);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/answer/add",
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ERROR, DB error");
            }
        });
```

Server-side:

```
router.post('/api/answer/add', function (req, res) {
    console.log('/api/answer/add: ', req.body)
```

Server-log:

```
/api/answer/add:  undefined
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(json) return string but contentType: "application/json". Try remove `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Have add `bodyParser.json()` in the `app.use`? like `app.use(bodyParser.json());`?

Comment: Also try to remove `JSON.stringify(` from `data: JSON.stringify(json),`

Comment: YES! missing app.use(bodyParser.json()); seems to be the case. And may-be a couple of other things. The app.js files were different between both projects. Many, thanks! P.S: If out put it as answer, I'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    json = { "auth_user_pkref": 2 }
    json.test_id = "ANCA"
    json.questions_count = 3
    json.right_answers = 2
    json.wrong_answers = 1
    json.seconds_spent = 180

    console.log('/api/answer/add', json);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/answer/add",
        type: "post",
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ERROR, DB error");
        }
    });
```

Try this